# How to create a ocfs2 filesystem in ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, cluster

Can someone please walk me through the step-by-step process of configuring a ocfs2 filesystem right from splitting an existing partition? When I tried, I am seeing the below error:

```
mount.ocfs2: Cluster name is invalid while trying to join the group
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and could solve it as follows:

There was an entry missing in the file `/etc/default/o2cb`.

```
# O2CB_STACK: The name of the cluster stack backing O2CB.
O2CB_STACK=o2cb
```

After adding the missing entry and saving I just restarted all related services. Now I could mount the drive

Comment: Please take the [Tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn how Q&A sites like StackExchange differ from internet discussion boards. Also please check out Asking- and Answering -sections in the [Help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) for advice how questions and answers should be formulated. [From Review](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/first-answers/390604)